# How to change UI of a cardview/dialog on button click?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, user-interface, expandablelistview, android-cardview

[image: Dialog UI 1]

[image: Dialog UI 2]

I want to change UI contents of a cardview on selection of a radio button, the example shown above is of Add Reminder from Google Keep, it changes the card contents when we select different radio option. It should animate while expanding or collapsing according to the contents. How can I achieve this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Use two layouts in just play with visibility on radio button state change.

Comment: Yes I tried that, the contents get hidden, but the extra space remains as it is! The card doesn't adjust its size when contents are hidden!!!

Comment: use visibility to gone not invisible.